# Weird behavior when importing a mesh in wavefront (obj) format with double-sided faces

Tags: mesh, materials, objects, import

Since the dataset I use, ShapeNet, contains a large number of obj files with **double sides faces**, importing it directly into blender and rendering image seems have incorrect materials.

To verify this, I give a simple example. The Box obj file contains 8 vertices and **24 triangle faces**, that is, 12 faces for Box, but each of them is double-sided. All face has correct normal.

**I think this example is simple enough that everyone can reproduce this bug in blender.**

For the 6 faces, I set them to the same material, and the other 6 are the second material. The same is true for the 12 inside faces, but the inside material is opposite to the materials of the face facing the outside.

The content of obj file is as follows:

```
mtllib model.mtl
vn 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v -0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v -0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
# 8 vertices, 0 vertices normals

usemtl material_0_24
f 1//1 2//2 3//3
f 4//4 3//3 2//2
f 1//1 3//3 5//5
f 7//7 5//5 3//3
f 1//1 5//5 2//2
f 6//6 2//2 5//5
f 7//7 6//6 8//8
f 6//6 7//7 5//5
f 4//4 7//7 8//8
f 7//7 4//4 3//3
f 6//6 4//4 8//8
f 4//4 6//6 2//2

usemtl material_4_24
f 3//3 2//2 1//1
f 2//2 3//3 4//4
f 5//5 3//3 1//1
f 3//3 5//5 7//7
f 2//2 5//5 1//1
f 5//5 2//2 6//6
f 8//8 6//6 7//7
f 5//5 7//7 6//6
f 8//8 7//7 4//4
f 3//3 4//4 7//7
f 8//8 4//4 6//6
f 2//2 6//6 4//4
```

And the content of model.mtl is as follows:

```
# Blender MTL File: 'blank.blend'
# Material Count: 2

newmtl material_0_24
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.000000 0.313726 0.000000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni -1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

newmtl material_4_24
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.800000 0.000000 0.000000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni -1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

When I use Meshlab to open obj and set the backface culling, the colors are displayed correctly, of which 6 are blue and the other is red. And Meshlab will show that the current obj has 24 faces and 8 vertices.
[image: meshlab screenshot]

But when I import this box obj to Blender, I found some double sides faces have been removed and there are only 12 faces.

Not only that, **Blender seems to delete some faces randomly**, resulting in inconsistent effects with Meshlab with backface culling turned on.
[image: blender screenshot]

Besides, Blender shows that there are currently **only 12 faces**, which means that double sides faces with the same vertex position are removed during the import process, but the removal criteria is strange.

[image: faces]

I want to know if this behavior is normal, if it is a bug in blender? If not, how should I config it to make the correct backface culling and display the correct faces and materials?